# Specifying the Source of Toolbox-parsed AST

Tags: scala, parsing, compilation, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm using a toolbox from Scala's compiler API to compile code into ASTs and then dissecting/splicing them and combining them into a single tree.  For debugging purposes I'm trying to track which nodes came from which source code.

Example:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

// obtain toolbox
val tb = runtimeMirror(this.getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
// get and parse source code from file
val myCode = scala.io.Source.fromFile("MyCode.scala").mkString
val myTree = tb.parse(myCode)
// get and parse dynamically-generated source code
val genCode = com.example.CodeGenerator.gimmeCode
val genTree = tb.parse(genCode)
// get and parse source code from a string literal
val literalCode = """println("to life, the universe, and everything")"""
val literalTree = tb.parse(literalCode)
// an over-simplified combination of the trees
val frankensteinsTree = q"$myTree;$genTree;$literalTree"

// walk the tree an print the source of each element
val traverser = new Traverser() {

  override def traverse(tree: Tree): Unit = {

    println("This node originated from " + tree.pos.source)
    super.traverse(tree)
  }
}

// the root element prints "This node originated from <no source file>"
// the rest print "This node originated from <toolbox>"
traverser.traverse(frankensteinsTree)
```

In the above example all but the root node show that the source is the `<toolbox>`.  (The root node says `<no source file>`.)  Before dissecting and recombining them, is there a way to specify tree.pos.source to identify each node's actual origin instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it can't currently (as of 2020-05-28) be done.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
println("Position is:  " + "MyCode" + tree.pos.toString.stripPrefix("source-<toolbox>"))
// Position is:  MyCode,line-1,offset=7
```

?

---

Try

```
val p = tree.pos
val pointMessage  = if (p.point > p.source.length) "out-of-bounds-" else "offset="
println(
  s"source-${p.source.file.canonicalPath},INSERT WHAT YOU WANT,line-${p.line},$pointMessage${p.point}"
) // source-<toolbox>,INSERT WHAT YOU WANT,line-1,offset=7
```

Comment: No, though that's similar to my current approach.  Check out the [Position trait](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/Position.html) of which type the pos method returns.  You'll see it has a `source` method which returns a SourceFile object.  This is where "source-<toolbox>" is specified along with the line and number.  I want to know if there's a way to parse the code so that it specifies "MyCode" or whatever description I choose instead of (or in addition to) "source-<toolbox>".

Comment: What do you mean by "so that it specifies "MyCode""? It's not clear what you try to achieve. You should reformulate your question better explaining why you are not satisfied with your current approach. `source-<toolbox>,line-1,offset=7` comes from here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/util/Position.scala#L91

Comment: I added a bit of context to my question.  Hope that explains it better.

Comment: Alternatively you can change that line in compiler source code, build it, and compile your code with this patched version of compiler.

Comment: If three ASTs from three different sources (we'll call the sources "MyCode", "YourCode", and "TheirCode") are dissected and recombined into a single Frankenstein's tree, I don't see how the proposed solution helps identify which elements in the combined tree come from which sources.  How does one determine which of the three source descriptions to insert when selecting an element from the combined tree and printing its pos object?

Comment: Sorry but you should write [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with "MyCode", "YourCode", and "TheirCode".

Comment: Done.  Is what I'm asking possible?

Comment: @Sledge Thanks for example. Sorry for late response. I would print something like `val p = tree.pos`
      `val pointMessage  = if (p == NoPosition) "" else if (p.point > p.source.length) "out-of-bounds-" else "offset="`
      `println(s"This node originated from tree=$tree, line-${p.line}, $pointMessage${if (p == NoPosition) "NoPosition" else p.point}")` If tree is too large then I'd print only the beginning of its string representation.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't provide the **source** of the parsed code. If the string to be parsed originates from a file, or dynamically generated from some other area of the program (and in most cases one of these two will be the case), there's little that allows it to traced back to its origin such as "CodeFragment.scala" or "generated by com.example.SourceCodeGenerater". Hence the question "Is it possible to change the `tree.pos.source` object?". That object exists explicitly for the purpose specifying a tree's code of origin.  If you know if such a thing is possible, please let me know.

Comment: What should be the source in your example for tree1, tree2, tree3, frankensteinsTree? I doubt the source can be changed programmatically. As I said above it's possible to change compiler source code, build it, and compile your code with this patched version of compiler. The question is how to change.

Comment: Let's say that tree1 has been compiled from the contents of the file MyTree.scala, tree2 from the method com.example.CodeBuilder.gimmeCode, tree3 from a string literal, and frankensteinsTree exactly as presented (not from any source code, but built programmaticly by combining the other three trees). I doubt the source be changed programmatically, as well, but I don't know for sure.  I ask in hopes of getting a definitive answer; either "Yes, and here's how..." or "No, it can't be done."